# How to get or add contacts to users Exchange mailbox?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

Wondering if anybody know: How to get or add contacts to users mailbox, using account with admin rights to access them in Exchange 2007. coding in C# 2008.

Searching for 4 days already cant find any examples of this solution.

Comment: Where is the code going to live? On the user's machine, on the Exchange server, somewhere else? This is important, as it affects what technology(ies) you can choose from.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using EWS since you are using C#. [MSDN: Exchange Web Services Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx)

There is also the Managed API which simplifies the calls.  [MSDN: Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.0 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710.aspx)